# Windows Forms program shows menu items as checked in designer and as a colored block when program runs

Tags: windows, forms, menu, checked

I've written a program in VS using C#, Forms and .Net Framework 4.8.  In the Designer, menu items show as checked.  When I run the program the items show with a colored block instead of a check. I've searched but can't seem to find any reference to a problem like this.
[Menu in Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9dGG.png)

[Menu at run-time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oxL9.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.  On the menuitem properties, there's a property called "ImageScaling" that defaults to 'SizeToFit'.  As soon as I set that to 'None' the check mark was in a small blue box (as I wanted it to be).  Thanks for your attention.